# ASP.NET Entity Framework Code First, Model Classes with Complex-type Properties Can not be Recorded on Local Database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have been a webforms guy for a long time but I think it is time to move to ASP.NET MVC programming.

During my studies of MVC I came accross this example of creating a music store. Everything was fine until section 4, where you are required to populate the database with some pre-defined data. I had the problem when I was trying to achieve that. Apparently the problem was when trying to write Album Model objects, which had Author and Genre types as properties, to localDB using Entity Framework Code-first approach.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-4

Seems like I have a problem with the Album class structure. In the tutorial Album class has 2 complex types:

```
public Genre    Genre       { get; set; }
public Artist   Artist      { get; set; }
```

And when I try to record them in the dbcontext as below, nothing happens. No data is written:(code in SampleData.cs)

```
var albums = new List<Album>
{
new Album { Title = "Worlds", Genre = genres.Single(g => g.Name == "Rock"), Price = 8.99M,Artist = artists.Single(a => a.Name == "Accept"),BookArtUrl = "/Content/Images/placeholder.gif" 
}
};
foreach (var al in albums)
{
  context.Albums.Add(al);
}
```

But when I change the complex types in Album class to be strings:

```
public string    Genre       { get; set; }
public string   Artist      { get; set; }
```

I can record them as below:(code in SampleData.cs)

```
var albums = new List<Album>
{
new Album { Title = "Worlds", Genre = (genres.Single(g => g.Name == "Rock")).ToString(), Price = 8.99M,Artist = (artists.Single(a => a.Name == "Accept")).ToString(),BookArtUrl = "/Content/Images/placeholder.gif" 
}
};
foreach (var al in albums)
{
  context.Albums.Add(al);
}
```

I don't know why it worked in the tutorial but not my exercise.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try making your object properties virtual (so they can be overriden by EF Code First):

```
public virtual Genre    Genre       { get; set; }
public virtual Artist   Artist      { get; set; }
```

You can also implicitly add GenreID and ArtistID foreign key fields and set a link to child entity manually (using attributes):

```
public int GenreID {get; set;} 
public int ArtistID {get; set;} 

[ForeignKey("GenreID")]
public virtual Genre    Genre       { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("ArtistID")]
public virtual Artist   Artist      { get; set; }
```